# What is a better design for storing user preference in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, schema

I have this object model in Google app engine

```
class UserPref(ndb.Model):
  user_id = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User')
  setting_a = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)
  setting_b = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)
  setting_c = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)
```

Recently I have to rename an attribute and it prompts me thinking what could be a better design:

A) use three rows to capture one row of information in the original design

```
class UserPref(ndb.Model):
  user_id = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User')
  setting_name = ndb.StringProperty()
  setting_value = ndb.StringProperty()
```

B) Repeated property

```
class UserPrefProp(ndb.Model):
  setting_name = ndb.StringProperty()
  setting_value = ndb.StringProperty()

class UserPref(ndb.Model):
  user_id = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User')
  Prop = ndb.StructuredProperty(UserPrefProp, repeated=true)
```

What are the pro and cons to these designs? Search for a setting is not important now, but it could change in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I think this is the way to go unless you have an unholy number of preferences:

```
class UserPref(ndb.Model):
  user_id = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User')
  setting_a = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)
  setting_b = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)
  setting_c = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)
```

The reason is that you can always add preferences, and unlike a relational datastore, you won't need to modify existing rows to get them up to date. For example if you add setting_d to the above schema midway through your project, existing entries will just have a None value returned for setting_d until the property is populated.

I think having `setting_name` and `setting_value` properties completely misses the point of ndb. That kind of schema is only useful in relational databases where you need to know the entire schema ahead of time. Since you can dynamically add properties to an ndb model, there's no reason to not just make each preference its own property.